# Capturing the RTSP streaming using libcurl

Tags: c, sockets, libcurl

How can I capture the RTSP streaming using socket connection ? 
I don't want to use opencv libraries.
If there is any alternatives libraries please suggest.

If we use libcurl how can we proceed?

Please help me. I am new to this libraries.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the libcurl example at below link

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html

Comment: can we do socket programming using this libcurl libraries?

Comment: According to libcurl website [link](https://curl.haxx.se/)  DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP.....and many more. So it is mainly targeting protocols developed on top of basic socket. if you want to do socket programming check BSD socket [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)

Comment: How can we capture video data after streaming using libcurl? Is there any way to do ? Please suggest with an example....

Answer (score 0):

Use FFmpeg

ffmpeg -i rtsp://@HOST:PORT -acodec copy -vcodec copy  D:/test.mp4

Comment: other than ffmpeg can't we use libcurl ?

Comment: But I think that ffmpeg is faster

Comment: can we capture the streaming using socket connection? and How to do ?